# EPS Returning CMYK result for all type of color format

Tags: c#, imagemagick, ghostscript, eps, magick.net

I am processing all `*.eps` files using ImageMagick/Ghostscipt and get the color profiles of each image and display the result. But I am getting same result as CMYK for grayscale, RGB, CMYK.
I don't know where I'm doing a mistake or which property will get the exact result.

**C# code**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    using ImageMagick;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var epsFile in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\tmp\eps", "*.eps"))
            {
                using (var image = new MagickImage())
                {
                    image.Read(epsFile);

                    Console.WriteLine("file: {0}   color space: {1}", epsFile, image.ColorSpace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

```
file: c:\tmp\eps\a.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\b.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\c.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\circle.eps   color space: sRGB
file: c:\tmp\eps\d.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\e.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\f.eps   color space: Grayscale
file: c:\tmp\eps\football_logo.eps   color space: sRGB
file: c:\tmp\eps\fsu_logo.eps   color space: sRGB
file: c:\tmp\eps\g.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\icam_logo.eps   color space: sRGB
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**But result currently coming is**

```
file: c:\tmp\eps\a.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\b.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\c.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\circle.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\d.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\e.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\f.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\football_logo.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\fsu_logo.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\g.eps   color space: CMYK
file: c:\tmp\eps\icam_logo.eps   color space: CMYK
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Are you sure `circle.eps` and the others aren't actually CYMK color-space images? Try to [convert them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18918798/75500) and recheck.

Comment: In my case the circle.eps is RGB. inside circle there are three combination of colors are available so that its result should be RGB. I did not required conversion I just need to know what is the current profile of the each image.

Comment: I know you don't want to convert. I merely suggested you should try to convert and see if Magick recognizes the colorspace it converted by itself. How are you so sure the colorspace for the circle is RGB?

Comment: Thanks shimmy for your suggestion, here I am mentioning circle, a, ...etc is for illustrate purpose only, the actual file is different and I opened the actual files in adobe software and checked the format. I will check and try your suggestion by converting them. In the mean time can you tell me that imagemagick having any other property for showing the perfect color profile or else Is any other library is there to fulfill my requirement. I am just beginner to Dot net....

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close this question as a problem that _cannot be reproduced_ or a duplicate of your original [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088356/how-to-read-the-property-or-color-information-of-eps-using-c/32089063#32089063). The code above is from my answer to that question and I'm pretty sure you're not getting the listed output from all those EPS files. Why? _Because they reside in my TMP folder, on my laptop, in my bag at home._ If you post your own files, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Don`t get tempted Micke, I am not duplicating I just need to know where I am doing mistake sorry if I mis understood anything. I will post the original file soon.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution to this is to override the PostScript operators which are used to set colour spaces, such as setrgbcolor, setgray, setcmykcolor and setcolorspace.

Eg:

```
/system_setrgbcolor /setrgbcolor load def

/setrgbcolor {
  (EPS file used setrgbcolor) == flush
  system_setrgbcolor
}bind def
```

Or a somewhat more sophisticated solution:

```
/MyDict 10 dict def
/MyDict begin
/UsedRGB false def
/UsedGray false def
/UsedCMYK false def
end

/system_setrgbcolor /setrgbcolor load def

/setrgbcolor {
  /MyDict /UsedRGB get not {
    (EPS file used setrgbcolor) == flush
    /MyDict /UsedRGB true put
  } if
  system_setrgbcolor
  end
}bind def
```

The latter should only print the first usage of the colour space.

NB this code is untested and may contain bugs.

Comment: Why override? is this find the actual color property of the eps file?

Comment: Because overriding the operator allows you to detect its use. That way you can be absolutely guaranteed that the colour space is used. EPS files don't have a 'color property', they can use any of; Gray, RGB, CMYK, CIEA, CIEABC, CIEDEF, CIEDEFG, DeviceN or Separation. In addition they can use any or all of these in the same file.